# How can I migrate some topics in kafka to a new cluster without any downtime

Tags: apache-kafka

The existing kafka cluster in our company is very large, and there is only one. We want to divide it into several small clusters according to the topic dimension. Do you have any good solutions?
Note: Our client cannot be shut down and restart.

We are trying to implement the return of modified metadata by adding a layer of agents, but I wonder if it is feasible

Comment: Do you use Confluent Kafka or just Apache Kafka?

Comment: just Apache Kafka

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker2 is the built-in tool to replicate topics to other Kafka clusters, but there are other solutions that exist.

Answer (score -1):

Please look in [this article](https://medium.com/@sanchitbansal26/how-to-migrate-kafka-cluster-with-no-downtime-58c216129058) under the title of "A Stretched Cluster with topic movement". It suggests to use kafka-reassign-partitions.sh command with a json file and without restarting the cluster. I hope this solves your question.

Comment: `kafka-reassign-partitions` only works within the same cluster. This blog is about expanding an existing cluster across regional datacenters.